# Why must I use Qt Designer 2.7 with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator

Why can't I use other Qt series with different Python releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. If you have a specific version of Qt you would like to use, you can either download a matching PyQt version from Riverbank's [download site](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) or you can compile your own version of PyQt. I've had to build them from scratch a few times when the provided binaries didn't match the Qt/Python versions I wanted to use. It's a bit of a hassle to compile but it's definitely possible.

Also, note that the up-and-coming [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) library is an alternative Qt binding for Python that looks like it has a good chance of supplanting PyQt (due to looser licensing constraints).

Generally speaking, Qt Designer is an optional and independent component from PyQt. You can use it to create your .ui files but after that, it's up to the developer to determine how to use them... either generate Python code from them with pyuic4 or load them dynamically. As long as the format of the resulting .ui files are compatible with your version of PyQt, it shouldn't matter which Designer version you're using (though I would strongly recommend you use the version matching the Qt version PyQt is linked against).